# ZIP file with EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, zip, xp-cmdshell

I am using the following code to zip a csv file and pdf. My issue is that I get an error that says:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
>
> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

the above error refers to the first '+ @Imagename +'

```
declare  @Imagename NVARCHAR(4000) 

set @Imagename = '343434'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 "D:\PO_PICKUP\'+ @Imagename +'.ZIP" "D:\PO_PICKUP\'+ @Imagename +'.csv" "D:\PO_PICKUP\'+ @Imagename +'.pdf"'
```

Think my issue is with the quotes and double quotes but I just cant figure it out.
When I give the code a static value as follows it works.  :

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 "D:\PO_PICKUP\34.ZIP" "D:\PO_PICKUP\34.csv" "D:\PO_PICKUP\34.pdf"'
```

What am I missing in the code with a variable?

Comment: You can't pass an expression for a parameter to a procedure. You'll need to assign the value to a variable, and pass that. Though *why* you would want to use SQL Server to create a zip file is a completely different question: smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info)

Comment: The 3rd party program needs the 2 files to be in one zip file.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you're using SQL Server to do this task.

Comment: There is no other programs loaded on the server other than SQL Server and WINRAR. The only other way is to use PI/PO which I dont have control of.

Comment: Powershell exists, and every Windows Instance since Windows XP has had that.

Comment: I dont have experience with Powershell. Why would it be an issue to use SQL Server to create a ZIP file?

Comment: Because that is not what SQL Server is made for. TSQL is not a generalized scripting language. Yes you can hack it but why would you? You can run these exact commands in `cmd` or Powershell. `xp_cmdshell` just passes commands to `cmd` anyway, why would you want another level of indirection?

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` is a **very** powerful and *dangerous* tool, @JCW . Someone with access to that procedure can do **literally** anything the service account that SQL Server is running under can do; this can often mean users have more power than they normally would. That doesn't mean you *shouldn't* use it (in general), but there are very few times where it should be; Zipping a file is not one of them.

Comment: You've also got some issues here launching WinRAR.exe, in particular, from xp_cmdshell. First, WinRAR.exe needs a desktop, and the account under which SQL Server is configured to run may not be allowed to have a desktop. Second, WinRAR.exe is asynchronous, so xp_cmdshell will return control to SQL Server before WinRAR has even finished its task(s), which could present some timing problems. Avoid xp_cmdshell where possible, but especially don't use it with GUI programs.

Comment: Did research on Powershell. Might not be the correct way but here is my solution:  ```set @Imagename2 = 'powershell.exe -Command "Compress-Archive -Path D:\PO_PICKUP\'+@Imagename+'.csv" -DestinationPath "D:\PO_PICKUP\'+@Imagename+'.zip" -Force'
print @Imagename2
  EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Imagename2;

 
set @Imagename2 = 'powershell.exe -Command "Compress-Archive -Path D:\PO_PICKUP\'+@Imagename+'.pdf" -Update -DestinationPath "D:\PO_PICKUP\'+@Imagename+'.zip"'
print @Imagename2
  EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Imagename2;````

Comment: @JCW still the wrong approach. Why do this from TSQL at all? If you need to run a Powershell command, do that from Powershell directly, not TSQL. You can even create a SQL Server Agent Job in Powershell language if you really want.